# Google speech to text api android

Tags: android, google-speech-api

Android google speech to text SDK, the voice recording is controlled by SDK .
I need to make it manual button for start and stop voice recording for speech to text. for eg: while click a button for start the voice recognition , its continue to record the audio until click the stop button. but in android SDK , its automatically stop the recording and pass the recorded audio for processing.

Comment: Please edit your question and post what did you try.

Answer (score 1):

I created an updated version of the Android sample application with Start and Stop, and posted it here:

https://github.com/Avilaaiops/SpeechRecognitionClient

It updates Gradle to 4.0.1, Kotlin to 1.3.72, and the Speech SDK to 1.24.0

This should help people looking for an up to date sample that isn't on the alpha SDK anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know this is how its attended to work. There is no continuous speech recognition. To implement something like you requested, you need to use third party libraries like [this](https://github.com/vikramezhil/DroidSpeech) or [this](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialandroid/) one.

Comment: this library also auto stop the recording, and start translation. currently i am manually record the audio using start and stop button, then call the google api with that audio, if it size larger than api constraints then i split it into small packets and call the api separately , then concatenating the resultant data. but its not the best solution, also microsoft azure intent speech service also have some feature like this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official documentation on how to transcribe Audio from Streaming Input in **Android** yet but Java, C#, Go, Python and Node.JS.  However there is a sample [Android app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech) for the API. You can use it as a starting point and convert the [Java code](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#speech-streaming-mic-recognize-java) into Android Native code.

Note: Even though Android uses Java but it is a different version which is designed to fit the Android architecture.

Using the approach I mentioned above requires extra effort, research skill as well as your Java and Android Fundamental Programming Skill. **#thisisthehardway**

The easier way will be applying external libraries like [Droid Speech](https://github.com/vikramezhil/DroidSpeech) (As mentioned by @kAliert).

From the documentation of Droid Speech:

> **Droid Speech** aims to close this gap and provide unparalleled
>   optimisation of continuous speech recognition without any of the above
>   said issues. It is developed keeping in mind all the loopholes which
>   needs to be blocked to have the speech recognition run seamlessly in
>   an android device.

This would be relative easy but it is made by third party as you have no full control on it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For this i searched a lot, i didnt find any solution to implement **Microsoft speech to text api**. Finally i got the solution it worked for me , and hope i will work for you or it can help somebody who is searching. I am just mentioning the git repository link, Pickup the MainActivity.java,gradle(aap and project level) , layout xml and put in your project. Execute and enjoy the solution.

**Git repository link is**: [MircoSoftSpeechToText](https://github.com/GyanSAwasthi/MicrosoftStt)